# JavaScript Array Comparison in PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql

I have created an array in JavaScript that has the following form:
`[1,2,3,4]` 
I can access this array via `{{{myArray}}` in PostgreSql.
In Postgre I have a table in a database where one column is relevant to me and it is structured as follows:

```
[100,22]
[20,22]
[33,12]
.
.
```

I want to check if the column contains any element of myarray, and if so I want to display it with a select statement.

An Example would be :

```
myArray = [100,120,33]
column = [[100,22] , [20,22] ,[33,12]]

[Output]: [[100,22],[33,12]]
```

I've tried to execute this command before:

`SELECT * FROM myDatabase
WHERE 'interestedColumn' in unnest{{myArray});`

But it looks like Postgre is disturbing the shape of the array I get from JS.

Comment: `unnesst{{myArray})` is a syntax error. What did you actually write?

Comment: Please post the DDL of the `myDatabase` table that you are selecting from.

Comment: {{myArray}}} works only in my environment, it's a complete postgre environment with some more elements that don't exist and have been implemented
But you can replace {{{myArray}} with the array itself to test the whole thing.

Comment: @Bergi i edited the question and changed the array at the top, thanks

Comment: What is this environment? Now I'm curious! But I doubt it doesn't require matched parenthesis or defines a custom `unnesst` keyword (instead of `unnest`).

Comment: the environment in which i want to program the whole thing is foundry postgate. regarding unnest i mistyped, it is of course unnest

Comment: Are these JSON arrays or Postgres arrays?

Comment: myArray is a JS Array , im not sure about the column (should be postgre array because it is in the Table from the database which i am accessing via postgre)

Comment: If it's a js array, please post the javascript code that you are using to access the database.

Comment: I try to describe the structure a little bit more exactly. I have a JS function(myArray) which returns an array.Via {{myarray}} I call this function in PostGre and get a JS array to work with in PostGre.

Comment: "*I call this function in PostGre and get a JS array to work with in PostGre.*" - what? Please link the docs of how this works if you need help with it. Are you using an embedded V8 engine in Postgres? Or is this just a templating language that produces SQL code? Or something else? And there are no "js arrays" in Postgres afaik. There are only arrays (type `int[]`) or json arrays (type `json`/`jsonb`). Which is it?

Comment: As I said, it's PostGre with extended implementation, so for example JS function calls work. The kind of array I get then is of type int[].

Comment: Are you saying `SELECT {{myArray}} AS result;` retrieves an array without a syntax error? Then my answer should work as well.

Comment: @Bergi if I try this , i get the following error : Query results contains duplicate column name ?column?. Duplicate column names are not supported.

Comment: So apparently this `{{myArray}}` syntax cannot be used in an arbitrary expression context, it does not just "call a js function and get an array of type int[]" but does some other trickery. I suggest you [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with more details about this environment (and maybe examples of how you can use array-returning functions in other situations if you can't link documentation). The question "*I want to check if the column contains any element of myarray, and if so I want to display it with a select statement.*" is already answered.

Comment: But let me make some more guesses, assuming it actually is just a bad templating language: try `({{myArray}})` or `'{ {{myArray}} }'::int[]` or `ARRAY[{{myArray}}]`.

Comment: @Bergi ({{myArray}}) works ! Thanks.
If you change that in your answer , I could mark it as solved

Comment: Cool. I'm curious now: What does `SELECT '{{myArray}}'::text AS result` give?

Comment: @Bergi an empty string

Comment: The suggestion `({{myArray}})` worked for a single output, but for comparison I used your other suggestion  `ARRAY[{{myArray}}]` ) and it works fine.

The general solution for the comparison would be :
```SELECT *
FROM myDatabase
WHERE ARRAY [interestedColumn] && ARRAY [{{{myArray}}];
```
So if anyone is interested in the comparison, I think it would be better to adapt the answer and thank you for the suggestions

Comment: `ARRAY[interestedColumn]` should not be necessary, didn't you say that the column held arrays as well? If no, then `WHERE interestedColumn = ANY ARRAY[{{myArray}}]` should do fine.

Comment: @Bergi yes ur right ```SELECT * FROM myDatabase WHERE interestedColumn && ARRAY [{{myArray}}];``` works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [array *overlap* operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM myDatabase
WHERE 'interestedColumn' && ({{myArray}});
```

Comment: @sd3v We can only help with Postgres SQL syntax or using specific libraries like `node-postgres` with parameterised queries etc. I still don't know what your `{{myArray}}` syntax does.

Answer (score 0):

The IN postgresql operator is written as follows : `value IN (value1, value2, ...)`
You must convert your array `[10,12,12312]` to a character string like `(10, 12, ...)`